# How do I make a CountDown show/start at the same moment my Button gets enabled?

Tags: java, android, android-button, countdowntimer

"How do I make a CountDown show at the same moment my Button gets enabled ?"

Additional info regarding the button: the Buttons Job is it to click 5 times through a stringarray displayed in a Textview to then get disabled for 5 seconds to do the same task again.

so ..I would like a CountDown to visually show those 5 seconds(the time the button is enabled) count down for the User to see.

sadly I dont have an idea how to connect my Button with an CountDown to let it know its supposed to count down at that particular time the Button is enabled.

Also I would like for the CountDown to start  everytime the Button gets enabled.

I looked into https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer
but it doesnt seem to have a solution for that particular case.

thats my Code for the Button as of now :

```
next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (currentnumber == list.length) {
                currentnumber = 0;
            }
            if (Curclicks == mod - 1) {
                next_button.setEnabled(false);
                display.setText(list[currentnumber]);
                currentnumber++;


                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //the button will unlock after the delay specified
                        next_button.setEnabled(true);
                        Curclicks = 0;

                    }
                }, delay);

            } else {
                display.setText(list[currentnumber]);
                currentnumber++;

            }
            Curclicks++;

        }

    });
```

UI Thread code can solve that ?  :

```
  private void runThread() {

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    while (delay == 5000) { //delay = 5000 ( 5 secs)
                        try {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    timer.setText("" + delay);//timer=TxtView
                                }
                            });
                            Thread.sleep(300);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
```

Comment: Do you want to display your button after the timer count (5 second) is complete?

Comment: "How do I make a CountDownTimer show at the same moment my Button gets enabled ?" A `CountDownTimer` is not a visual element. You can not "show" it. Beside that I see no `CountDownTimer` in your code.

Comment: The Button is transparent and always there, I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Yes there is no CountDownTimer because like I said I dont know how I connect the CountDownTimer with my Button

Comment: What do you mean with its not a visual element, isnt it used to display a certain time count down in your App ?
Edit: Alright I basically edited CountDownTimer to "CountDown" I hope now its a bit more clear to what im trying to do!

Comment: Is it now more clear ?

Comment: Yes that is more clear. I general I see a lot of developers have issues with the `CountDownTimer`... not just implementing it but also handling events like `onPause()` and proper disposal. I personally believe your attempt with the `Handler` with the `delay` parameter is a good approach. I have no idea which value you have chosen for "delay", but depending you the accuracy you wish to achieve keep it relatively small. Use mod to detect full seconds. Then you can use `runOnUiThread` for any changes you need to make to the UI.

Comment: Im a bloody beginner and never coded any Uithread, can u maybe tell me or show how its supposed to look I edited how I thought it would work in my Question, but nothing at all is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use the `postDelayed()` method of the `Handler` to create a count down. I have purposefully left the code a bit verbose so you can go through it step-by-step in order to see what is happening.

Create a few class variables and constants.

```
private static final long COUNT_DOWN_TICKS = 100l;
private static final long COUNT_DOWN_FINISH = 5000l;
private long countdownElapsed = 0l;
private Handler mCountDownHandler = new Handler();
```

`COUNT_DOWN_FINISH` is set to 5000 --> 5 sec. But can be changed to anything you need. Also I use `COUNT_DOWN_TICKS` set to 100 --> 0.1 sec, just in case you want to display a more precise count down.

From your `OnClick()` method just call `startCountDown()` to get the count down started.

```
private void startCountDown() {
    try {
        countdownElapsed = 0l;
        next_button.setEnabled(false);
        displayCountDown();
        mCountDownHandler.postDelayed(mCountDownRunnable, COUNT_DOWN_TICKS);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private Runnable mCountDownRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        countdownElapsed = countdownElapsed + COUNT_DOWN_TICKS;

        if(countdownElapsed >= COUNT_DOWN_FINISH){
            releaseCountDownHandler();
            next_button.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else{
            mCountDownHandler.postDelayed(mCountDownRunnable, COUNT_DOWN_TICKS);
        }

        long secFull = countdownElapsed % 1000;
        if(secFull == 0){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    displayCountDown();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

private void releaseCountDownHandler() {
    try {
        if(mCountDownRunnable != null) {
            mCountDownHandler.removeCallbacks(mCountDownRunnable);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}


private void displayCountDown(){
    long t = (COUNT_DOWN_FINISH - countdownElapsed)/1000;
    String myTime = String.valueOf(t);
    timer.setText(myTime);
}
```

In order to dispose of the `Runnable` properly you will want to call `releaseCountDownHandler()` from the `onPause()` method. This is just a short running `Thread`, but it should still not be ignored.

I prefer the `Handler` with the `postDelay()` method to the `Thread.sleep()` method--something about putting any thread to sleep is disconcerting. Also note that it is a good idea to get accustom to checking the elapsed time condition with ">=" RATHER than "==" depending on the implementation (e.g. you use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` instead) the condition just might miss the exact value!

---

**EDIT**

---

Somewhere under the definition of your `Activity` class (for this example I will call it `MainActivity`) you will need to declare a few variables. Since they are being defined inside the class and NOT inside a method the are referred to as "class variables"  and they have a scope of entire class when defined "private".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //class variables
    private static final long COUNT_DOWN_TICKS = 100l;
    private static final long COUNT_DOWN_FINISH = 5000l;
    private long countdownElapsed = 0l;
    private Handler mCountDownHandler = new Handler();
    private Button next_button;
    private TextView timer;


....    

}
```

You probably have declared the `onClick()` method inside the `onCreate()` method of the `MainActivity` class. So just add the following code:

```
next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startCountDown();
}
```

Everything else I provide are method inside the `MainActivity` class...NOT inside any other method. So below the `onCreate()` method add all methods that I previously posted.

It will look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    //class variables
    private static final long COUNT_DOWN_TICKS = 100l;
    private static final long COUNT_DOWN_FINISH = 5000l;
    private long countdownElapsed = 0l;
    private Handler mCountDownHandler = new Handler();
    private Button next_button;
    private TextView timer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // you must compensate for the actual layout for your activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // you must compensate for the actual id of the TextView
        timer = findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);

        // you must compensate for the actual id of the Button
        next_button = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startCountDown();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startCountDown() {
        try {
            countdownElapsed = 0l;
            next_button.setEnabled(false);
            displayCountDown();
            mCountDownHandler.postDelayed(mCountDownRunnable, COUNT_DOWN_TICKS);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Runnable mCountDownRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            countdownElapsed = countdownElapsed + COUNT_DOWN_TICKS;

            if(countdownElapsed >= COUNT_DOWN_FINISH){
                releaseCountDownHandler();
                next_button.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else{
                mCountDownHandler.postDelayed(mCountDownRunnable, COUNT_DOWN_TICKS);
            }

            long secFull = countdownElapsed % 1000;
            if(secFull == 0){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        displayCountDown();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    private void releaseCountDownHandler() {
        try {
            if(mCountDownRunnable != null) {
                mCountDownHandler.removeCallbacks(mCountDownRunnable);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private void displayCountDown(){
        long t = (COUNT_DOWN_FINISH - countdownElapsed)/1000;
        String myTime = String.valueOf(t);
        timer.setText(myTime); 
    }   

}
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, im trying to copy your Code in bracket after bracket ,however im getting some Errors, can you walk me through them ?

Comment: Sure, What kind of errors are you getting? I am a bit surprised because I did test this before posting, but you might have a scenario I did not test.

Comment: Alright so the errors are starting at private void startCountDown() 

1. "Variable 'startCountDown()' is never used" and then some error before and after the  () saying  either " ; expected " or "Expression expected" 

2.  and in the try logic  at  displayCountDown();  "cannot resolve method displayCountDown();"  and  in the brackets of mCountDownHandler.post delayed mCountDownRunnable colored red and says "Cannot resolve symbol 'mCountDownRunnable'

I think these a repetitive errors if you get me to solve those I think I can get the other stuff correct myself.

Comment: If u want to see the whole onClick method please let me know.

Comment: @Karlay :: Please take a look at the edit I just posted. This should get you back on track. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I needed this, I was able to reduce the Errors to only 1 and that is the only time countdownTicks is mentioned "Cannot resolve symbol 'countdownTicks'." and Im also wondering what countdownTicks would be reffering to, since its not a variable we had declared earlier. If I look for the options AndroidStudio has to offer for me it tells me to do one of those things " create local variable countdownTicks" or " Create field countDownTicks" or "Create parameter countDownTicks" or "Rename reference" . 
Im sure u can help me on that too ,I feel like I've learned a lot from you , ty

Comment: Also im wondering why you put an l at your variables above the onCreate method, if I remove that l im not getting errors, whats the use of it ?

Comment: Oh one last thing at the variables section I got a TAG error yesterday and searched on SO for a solution and found this Code and it did elimate the error however it looks different from your TAG variable is it fine to keep mine the way it is ? 
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

Comment: @Karlay :: Firstly, "countdownTicks" is indeed an error. Replace "countdownTicks" with "COUNT_DOWN_TICKS" ! As I copied the code from my computer to Stack Overflow I change "countdownTicks" from a variable to a constant value "COUNT_DOWN_TICKS" (using static final -- Java naming convention const are all caps). That should get ride of the last error.

Comment: @Karlay :: The "I" is actually a lowercase "L"! A lowercase as in `long`. This tell java that I am actually initializing the variable or const to a `long` type. Without it Java sometimes turns the value into a `int` instead of `long`. Quirky...

Comment: @Karlay :: As I mentioned  I simple assumed a class name for the `Activity`. I simple called it `MainActivity` and that your `Activity` class might have a different name. Generally, android coders will want to send a lot of information to the logcat. That will often look like `Log.e(TAG, "Got to onFinish");` letting the coder know that that part of the code executed..These Logs are often removed for release code. But having a "TAG"  makes things easier. So define `private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();` where "MainActivity"  should be the class name.

Comment: @Karlay :: The advantage of having the TAG written `private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();` with the class name is when you refactor the class for any reason this TAG name is automatically refactored.

Comment: Okay, I tested the Code just now, but its not like I envisioned it to be, it displays the 5 sec delay after EVERY click I do, but what I actually want is to display the 5 sec delay after clicking 5 times, so basically the same thing but at every 5th click not every click. ( my button without that Code of yours  got enabled after every 5th click for 5 secs)

Comment: Like maybe a if condition in the startCountDown method inside the OnClick ? but not sure what its supposed to look like.

Comment: nvm  I put the startCountdown(); into my  handler.postdelaed in my onClick, the problem now is that the visual CountDown starts 5~ sec after my delay started so basically at that point I can click again before the CountDown even started, why is that ?

Comment: nvm² I put the startCountDown(); into my if condition above the postdelayed now there is seemingly zero delay between my delay and the CountDown , what bothers me now though is the CountDown(Textview timer) I hint called "CountDown" , it never returns to the hint "CountDown" instead it just goes from 5 to 0 again and again(after it's first used), I would like it to show the hint when the CountDown reaches 0(or more clearly whenever the CountDown is not active), sorry for not being structured well y.y

Comment: How the code works:: At the start the button is enabled, the user clicks the button-> `onClick` is triggered and the method `startCountDown` is called. The button is disabled to prevent the user from starting a new count down during the 5secs. The `postDelay` method ensures that the `Runnable` is not called for 100ms. The elapsed time is checked to see if a full sec. has elapsed if "true"  the display is updated with the time remaining (in full secs.).  Once the 5 secs has elapsed the button is enabled and the user can restart the countdown as described above. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @Karlay :: Take a look at the new answer I posted. Maybe that is what your were wanting

Answer (score 0):

This function should do what you want, just call it into OnClickListener

```
public void countDown(Button yourBtn) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int second = 10;
                for (int i = second; i >= 1; i--) {
                    int finalI = i;
                    yourBtn.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            yourBtn.setText(String.valueOf(finalI))
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // Change text every 1s
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: whenever "second" is mentioned it tells me "cannot resolve symbol second" and at the arrow " (() ->  " it says "Lambda expressions are not supported at language level 1.7"

Comment: @Karlay sorry I edited the code, just forgot the int

Comment: okay thats better but it still says "Lambda expressions are not supported at language level 1.7"

Comment: @Karlay I removed the lambda expression for the normal one

Comment: but it still gives me the same error "Lambda expressions are not supported at language level 1.7"

Comment: No my bad I forgot the post() lambda function, it should be good now

Comment: Have to sleep now tired the Code, nothing happening,  im wondering though, why 

"  yourBtn.setText(String.valueOf(finalI)) " you want me to display the time left for the user with a button ?

Comment: Is that not what you want to do ? "I would like a CountDown to visually show those 5 seconds"

Comment: right, but I can also use a TextView instead of a Button right ? 
I get errors in the first line though  "Variable countDown is never used" and a bunch of " ; expected" "  )  expected"  I wrote  TextView timer(the ID ) instead of Button yourBtn in the brackets is that alright ?

Answer (score 0):

This code is like my code above except this code introduces a "click counter". I have introduced a new class variable to keep track of how many times the button is clicked. I have also introduced a new constant called "NUMBER_OF_BUTTON_CLICKS"  which servers as the upper limit of clicks.

The user can now click on the button (in this case) 5 times. On the fifth click the  condition to trigger the `startCountDown` method is met and the button is disabled for 5 seconds.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Constant values    
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_BUTTON_CLICKS = 5;
    private static final long COUNT_DOWN_TICKS = 100l;
    private static final long COUNT_DOWN_FINISH = 5000l;

    //class variables
    private int howManyClicks = 0;
    private long countdownElapsed = 0l;
    private Handler mCountDownHandler = new Handler();
    private Button next_button;
    private TextView timer;
    private TextView clicks;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // you must compensate for the actual layout for your activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // you must compensate for the actual id of the TextView
        timer = findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);

        // Use this only if you want to display the number of clicks 
        // you might need to add this TextView if you want to display the number of clicks
        clicks = findViewById(R.id.tvClicks);

        // you must compensate for the actual id of the Button
        next_button = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                howManyClicks++;
                if(howManyClicks >= NUMBER_OF_BUTTON_CLICKS){
                    startCountDown();
                }

                //Add this only if you want to see how many clicks were made
                String myClicks = String.valueOf(howManyClicks);
                clicks.setText(myClicks)
            }
        });
    }

    private void startCountDown() {
        try {
            countdownElapsed = 0l;
            next_button.setEnabled(false);
            displayCountDown();
            mCountDownHandler.postDelayed(mCountDownRunnable, COUNT_DOWN_TICKS);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Runnable mCountDownRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            countdownElapsed = countdownElapsed + COUNT_DOWN_TICKS;

            if(countdownElapsed >= COUNT_DOWN_FINISH){
                releaseCountDownHandler();
                next_button.setEnabled(true);
                // reset the clicks counter
                howManyClicks = 0;
            }
            else{
                mCountDownHandler.postDelayed(mCountDownRunnable, COUNT_DOWN_TICKS);
            }

            long secFull = countdownElapsed % 1000;
            if(secFull == 0){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        displayCountDown();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    private void releaseCountDownHandler() {
        try {
            if(mCountDownRunnable != null) {
                mCountDownHandler.removeCallbacks(mCountDownRunnable);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private void displayCountDown(){
        long t = (COUNT_DOWN_FINISH - countdownElapsed)/1000;
        String myTime = String.valueOf(t);
        timer.setText(myTime);

        //Add this only if you want to see how many clicks were made
        String myClicks = String.valueOf(howManyClicks);
        clicks.setText(myClicks)
    }   

}
```

Comment: Ty but, I solved that already by putting the startCountDown(); into this if condition  if (Curclicks == mod - 1) {
                    next_button.setEnabled(false);
                    display.setText(list[currentnumber]);
                    currentnumber++;
                    startCountDown();, I dont know if you reailzed, but I have Code in my onClick that u didnt write (see above).
My actual problem now is that my CountDown always goes from 5 to 0 , nothing more, but I would like it to go from 5 to 0 and then show its Text "CountDown"

Comment: I really like the show clicks feature !
Can we maybe put another Button that is responsible for going 1 String backwards AND/OR forward but only the ammount that my next_button has gone forward so the user can go back and forth between those 5 revealed strings , because actually I want to increase the delay to like 12 hours when im more advanced with the App, so it would be nice for the User to check what the 5 strings were saying again  , and then attach the Clicks counter to that to basically show something like 1/5 2/5 .. 5/5 depending on what String is being reviewed, know what I mean ?

Comment: Actually I realized that I want one button to go backwards and the other to go forwards(talking about reviewing the 5 revealed strings) the problem is that my button going forwards is enabled after the 5 clicks so I could only go backwards with the other button + each button takes 40% of my screen space (transparent), anything I can do to still make it work ? I hope u know what I mean